A problem about functional analysis.
Let $B=\{x\in\mathbb{R}^3\mid \vert x\vert\leqslant 1\}$, $0\leqslant\kappa^2\leqslant \frac{1}{4\pi^2}$. Prove that for any $u^{inc}\in L^2(B)$, there exists a unique solution $u\in L^2(B)$,such that
$$u(x)-\kappa^2\int_{B}\frac{e^{i\kappa\vert x-y\vert}}{\vert x-y\vert^{1/2}}(\vert x\vert-1)u(y)dy=u^{inc}(x)$$.
I think that Banach Fixed Point Theorem may work, however, I cannot prove that the map
$$Tu(x)=u^{inc}(x)+\kappa^2\int_{B}\frac{e^{i\kappa\vert x-y\vert}}{\vert x-y\vert^{1/2}}(\vert x\vert-1)u(y)dy$$
is a contraction map. Could anyone help?
By the way, does the "inc" stand for something? Could anyone give a short introduction? Thanks a lot!

Hint: Fredholm alternative
